# Setting Video ring tone programmatically

Tags: ios, video, ringtone

Is there any iOS framework or some 3rd party API, that allows the application to enable video ring tone? Will Apple approve this?
A similar app on Android is "Vringo" which enables to set video ring tones.

Can some one help me in identifying the right API please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not provide any framework or API that allows third party apps to change system settings, let alone set video ringtones.

iOS is a far more secure operating system than Android, primarily due to the fact that third party apps are not permitted or even able to change or affect system settings or behaviour, so apps like this cannot exist on iOS, except as jailbreak tweaks.

You may be able to achieve this with some hacking on a jailbroken device, but definitely not otherwise, and it definitely won't be approved.